# View count in mobile version of hinduism.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

Most of the times I browse the mobile version of this site. I also tried Android app of this site. I am happy with all features. Can we show view count somewhere along the side of each question? If it is not shown intentionally because of some reason (security etc) then it's fine.

Comment: Duplicate: [Is there a way to view the number of unique views for a question on a mobile device?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139613/163449). You can always click on [chrome] browser option and select "view as desktop site".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option of viewing number of views on a mobile device currently. The reason is that it is not available yet. We can only view this on full site.

This feature was proposed on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139613/357396) to add mobile views to mobile version also. The developers has not responded to it yet. There's also a link to the desktop version in the footer called "full site". We can switch mobile version and full site. If we want to check views of the site and other missing features, then select it and check the views.

[image]

Comment: You can also mentioned "request desktop site" option that is usually available in browser.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I use from mobile and when I want to check views I make desktop version enabled.

In various browser its kept in various way. For eg. In UC browser you can find it by clicking in 'full site' option available in bottom of page.

[image]

Similarly in default browser of mobiles also it's available in more option section:

[image]

In Chrome and Mozilla browsers also available similarly:
[image]

And finally you get desktop view with view counts also like this:

[image]

And you can also go to the mobile view by reaching in the same places in the respective browsers.